# Responsive image design with a set height

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

I wounder if any one can help me with a little problem with responsive images.

I have a height I want my image to be. 200 px and about 100% of the width of the container. That creates the problem that the images is stretched and don't look good. I wounder if theres any way I can make the images keep its ratios and still look good. can I have a container around it with a set height and make so the overflow is hidden behind every thing on the top and bottom and how do i do that the easiest way?

[image: How the site looks atm]

Any other sugestions how I can solve the problem?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You can use `background-size: cover`. Check this [**link**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/)

Comment: width:auto, height:200px. margin:0 auto

Answer (score 1):

The way you are solving this problem is wrong. You cannot put a constraint on both `height` and `width` and maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

As for this case, consider this CSS:

```
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a css attribute called `background-size` which I normally use for situations like this. `background-size` combined with `background-position` could be what you are looking for. Example below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://www.redcross.org/images/MEDIA_CustomProductCatalog/m17844381_TheHero_763x260_PRE.JPG');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my example the "hero" image is 763x260px and the container div that it is displayed in is 470x200px but it still fits in the "best way" to it's container.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it by using `background-size:cover`